# Guess Number Game GUI - Infinite Loop

Tags: java, loops, user-interface, random

I'm making a guess the number program and I'm having trouble with my loop. When I run the program and input a number into the textfield and hit enter it freezes. I figured out that this might be happening because of an infinite loop. Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong. Basically when I enter a number into the textfield and press enter it suppose to change a label and change background color but this doesn't happen and I think its because my loop runs until win becomes true and when I type in my number it keeps running that number instead of outputting the correct label and letting me input a different number into the textfield. P.S: I know the newGame button does not work yet

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class GuessingGame implements ActionListener 
{
    JFrame guessFrame;

    JPanel guessPanel;

    JTextField guessText;

    JButton newGame;

    JLabel rangeLbl, enterGuessLbl, winLbl;

    Random rand = new Random();
    int numToGuess = rand.nextInt(1000)+1;
    int numOfTries = 0;
    int guess;

   public GuessingGame() 
   {
        // Create the frame and container.
        guessFrame = new JFrame("Guess the Number");
        guessPanel = new JPanel();
        guessPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,0));


        // Add the widgets.
        addWidgets();

        // Add the panel to the frame.
        guessFrame.getContentPane().add(guessPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        // Exit when the window is closed.
        guessFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // Show the converter.
        guessFrame.pack();
        guessFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    // Create and add the widgets for converter.
    private void addWidgets() 
    {  
        // Create widgets.
        guessText = new JTextField();
        guessText.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
        rangeLbl = new JLabel("I have a number between 1 and 1000. Can you guess my number?", SwingConstants.LEFT);
        enterGuessLbl = new JLabel("Please enter your guess", SwingConstants.LEFT);
        winLbl = new JLabel(" ", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        newGame = new JButton("New Game");

        // Listen to events from Convert textfield.
        guessText.addActionListener(this);

        // Add widgets to container.
        guessPanel.add(rangeLbl);
        guessPanel.add(enterGuessLbl);
        guessPanel.add(guessText);
        guessPanel.add(winLbl);
        guessPanel.add(newGame);
    }

    // Implementation of ActionListener interface.
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) 
    {        
        boolean win = false;

        guess = Integer.parseInt(guessText.getText());

        if ( guess == numToGuess)
        {
            win = true;
        }
        else if ( guess < numToGuess)
        {
            winLbl.setText("Too Low");
            guessPanel.setBackground(Color.red);
            guess = Integer.parseInt(guessText.getText());
        }
        else if ( guess > numToGuess)
        {
            winLbl.setText("Too High");
            guessPanel.setBackground(Color.blue);
            guess = Integer.parseInt(guessText.getText());
        }

        winLbl.setText("Correct!");
        guessPanel.setBackground(Color.green);
    }  

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        GuessingGame game = new GuessingGame();
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your while-loop is inappropriate here, because you are in a `actionPerformed()` Method. This method is most likely to be called on a gui action (e.g. button kicked).

It should do one action corresponding to your needs and then terminate, since this method is invoked within the EDT. Your gui will not perform any updates until this method is finished.

Thus nothing will change (e.g. your win status) until the user makes some additional action, which he can't because your gui is frozen.

Comment: i think i'm understanding maybe I just edited the question to post the full code

Comment: remove the while loop as suggested, you don't need it here.

Comment: i removed the while loop and now any number i input is correct haha

Answer (score 0):

You don't update the value of guess. You'll need to read guess at the end of your loop, or at least in those cases that guess and numToGuess don't have the same value.

In the current case: if the values are not equal the first iteration, it will never become.

add

```
guess = Integer.parseInt(guessText.getText());
```

as last statement to each else if block

EDIT: a better way, as Marcinek points out, would be to remove the while loop, but since I don't know your requirements, I won't go as far as to claim it's the correct sollution.

Comment: i think i'm understanding maybe I just edited the question to post the full code

Comment: If you need the user to continue entering numbers until he's got it right, that would do it indeed. But you are also asking a new value, if he got the value correct. That is not needed. But do you need to iterate there, or only check the current value?

Comment: if he gets the random number correct  i'm suppose to make the textfield uneditable and show that it is correct . then to start a new game you would have to press the button . the user needs to continue to enter numbers into the textfield getting responses back until the guess is correct

Comment: Then remove the while loop. The actionPerformed will be executed each time you enter text/press a button/<whatever you've added the actionListener to>. And, since you don't have a loop anymore, you'll no longer immediately need to read a new value, it'll be done once the actionPerformed runs again.

Comment: i removed the while loop and now any number i input is correct haha i edited the code to show what I have as of now

Comment: @TubaShark: without the while block, remove these statements from the else-if blocks: guess = Integer.parseInt(guessText.getText());

Answer (score 0):

Your loop keep runing because this condition `if ( guess == numToGuess)` never verfied

```
         boolean win = false;

          while (win == false){

       if ( guess == numToGuess){
           win = true;
          }
            .......
           }
```

and 
win still false, and while loop go a head runing.

```
 while (win == false)
{
    .....}
```